# javascript function name vs function literal usage

Tags: javascript

When testing for a partial evaluation function:

```
function partialEval(fn)
   {
      var sliceMethod = Array.prototype.slice; 
      if(arguments.length > 1)
      {
        var aps = sliceMethod.call(arguments, 1);
      }


      return function () {
         return fn.apply(this,aps.concat(  sliceMethod.call(arguments)  ));  
    };

    }




    var x= function add(a,b,c,d){
     console.debug(a +  " - " +  b +  " - " +  c +  " - " +  d);
     return a+b+c+d; 

    }

    var pa = partialEval(add, 1,2); // Query here
    var zz = pa(3,4);
    console.debug(zz);
```

What is the difference between calling partialEval(add,1,2) and partialEval (x,1,2)?
I understand that x is a function literal here  and using x gives the correct results. But when I use add as a function name sent to the partialEval method the output is coming as 3. Can someone explain the execution differences between the two?

thanks.

Comment: `add` should not work here. Does it actually work?

Comment: @primvdb: It might in IE. IE has bugs regarding named function expressions.

Comment: @primvdb: It works in firefox 3.6 and I am testing with firebug..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
var x = function add(a,b,c,d){
  // code...
}
```

`add` should only exist inside the function (and refer to itself).  Outside of the function you need to use `x`, `add` will be `undefined`.

Comment: add is not coming as undefined. Check in FF

Comment: @Anna: Seems browsers all handle this differently.  I suggest *not* declaring functions like this, because the behavior as you can see is not the same.

Comment: Can one say that function literal definitions are almost equivalent to anonymous function then? Is there no difference in terms of usage?

Comment: @Anna: `var x = function(a,b,c,d){}` is *exactly* the same as `function x(a,b,c,d){}`.

Comment: @Anna: What do you mean by "function literal definitions are almost equivalent to anonymous function"?

Comment: var x = function(a,b,c,d){}  -> Anonymous function                       var x = function add(a,b,c,d){}  -> named function assigned to a variable.   .. Any utility/difference of using named functions assigned to a variable then ?

Comment: @Rocket let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2822/discussion-between-anna-and-rocket)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that named functions are hoisted whereas function literals are not.

No reason to use both types though. I generally use an anonymous function literal as in my mind it maps them as objects, which they are.